# Google Play - Security Alert for unsafe unzipping pattern vulnerability

Tags: android-security

I have an android application uploaded in google play store which uses Zoom SDK. I have recently got an alert from play console that the app contains an unsafe unzipping pattern that may lead to a Path Traversal vulnerability at location us.zoom.androidlib.util.FileUtils.unzipFile .I think it is a bug from zoom sdk and needs to be resolved by them. Can any one know how to fix this issue?

Zoom sdk is used for Zoom calling functionality. we only using zoom sdk , no other configuration file are used in application. even its showing this security error from google play.Zoom Sdk need to look this security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this errors by checking if canonical paths to unzipped files or not.

Check if again the return value of `File.GetCanonicalPath()` belongs to the intended directory path.